# Mathematical equation of the obliquely balanced system

Tags: torque, equilibrium

why doesn't the system behave like a pendulum?

*1. state of equilibrium* (the pivot point of the bar is at the center of gravity)

[image]

How do we write the equilibrium equation of the system in the 1st equilibrium state, i.e. why is the rod in equilibrium at a certain angle.

*2. state* (the pivot point of the bar is at the center of gravity)

[image]

In case 2, if I turn the rod a little to the left and release it, the rod moves to the right and the 1st equilibrium state returns, what was the force acting on the rod, how do I write the equation of the force acting? ?

**Note:The images are from the "Algodoo" physics simulator.**

Answer (score 1):

The pivot point may be at the center of gravity of the bar, but it is not at the center of gravity of the system. A careful examination of the diagram indicates that each mass is shifted a little to the right relative to the bar. At equilibrium the center of mass of the system will lie below the pivot point and:
${m_1}gR sin(θ_1) = {m_2}gR sin(θ_2)$ with the θ's measured from the vertical to the center of each mass. If displaced from equilibrium, the system will oscillate like a physical pendulum.